# How to convert a queryset quickly?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Through an ajax request I request data from the database that has 70 thousand lines. The query is very fast, it lasts 0.2 seconds but I can't return it because I can't return queryset by JsonResponse, so I have to convert it to json but that's the problem. How to convert as fast as possible? I tried using the following code, but it still takes like 6 seconds.

```
queryset = Users.objects.all()
list = []
[list.append({"id": query.id, "name": query.name}) for query in queryset]
return JSONResponse(list, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) queryset the resulting rows are already a dict with the selected keys

```
values = Users.objects.values('id', 'name')
return JSONResponse(list(values), safe=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to display all 70k records at once?

If not, then use pagination and you will have to convert siginifically less data.

Check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/pagination/

and https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/